# Webkit browsers not displaying background image / padding?

Tags: css, image, webkit, background

We're having a problem with our website at www.tonerize.com, in regards to the blue menu at the top center of the page. In IE / Firefox / Most browsers, the menu displays correctly and has a background image.

However, in Webkit based browsers (Chrome, Safari, etc), the menu doesn't have a background and it seems like the padding is not being used. Is there any reason for this?

Answer (score -1):

We figured this out. Webkit wasn't liking on of the tags in the CSS, which other browsers apparently ignored.

Comment: Please mark you're question as answered. You can do this even if you answered it yourself. By the way, try to be more detailed by telling which 'tag' webkit had problems with, so others who have similar problems can consult this thread.